# Codeigniter Update Batch Error

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I tried to find solutions
but i always get this error

> You must specify an index to match on for batch updates.

```
public function editcompanionship()
        {
            $companionship_id = $this->input->post('companionship_id[]');
            $missionary_one_id = $this->input->post('missionary_one_id[]');
            $missionary_two_id = $this->input->post('missionary_two_id[]');
            $missionary_three_id = $this->input->post('missionary_three_id[]');

            $value_batch_update = array();

            for($i=0; $i<count($companionship_id); $i++):
                $value_batch_update[$i] = array(

                    'missionary_one_id'     =>      $missionary_one_id[$i],
                    'missionary_two_id'     =>      $missionary_two_id[$i],
                    'missionary_three_id'   =>      $missionary_three_id[$i],
                    'modified'              =>      date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()),

                );
            endfor;
            $this->db->where('companionship_id',$companionship_id[$i]);
            $this->db->update_batch('pcdom_companionship',$value_batch_update);
            $this->session->set_flashdata("success",alert("alert-success","Updated Successfully!"));
            redirect(base_url('mrec/companionship'));
            exit();
        }
```

Can Any body knows?

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd param of method update_batch() is required.

```
public function update_batch($table, $set = NULL, $index = NULL, $batch_size = 100)
    {
        ....

        if ($index === NULL)
        {
            return ($this->db_debug) ? $this->display_error('db_must_use_index') : FALSE;
        }
        ...
```